# Красный значок в Source Tree git

Tags: git, github

Установил Source Tree, авторизовал через GitHub OAuth, добавил OpenSSH ключ, и вижу вот такой красный значок:
[image: ?]

Тем не менее отправить, получить и синхронизировать работают!
Подскажите пожалуйста что мне делать, я Git учу 3 дня)

Comment: учить git через source tree - ещё то удовольствие. Мне как минимум известно три случая, когда баги в этой, не побоюсь сказать, поделке, заставляли людей седеть. Лучше разберитесь, как оно работает в консоли.

Comment: Я её поставил, но учусь в консоли

Comment: Я поставил просто для интереса

Comment: А всё, значок изчез, я убрал в ссылке на origin .git и заново ввёл!